# Search a tensor for data/values

Tags: python, pytorch

Given:

```
tensor([[6, 6],
        [4, 8],
        [7, 5],
        [7, 4],
        [6, 4]])
```

How do I find the index of rows with values `[7,5]`?

In general, how do I search for indices of any values: full and partial row or column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
>>> (a[:, None] == torch.tensor([7, 5])).all(-1).any(-1).nonzero().flatten().item()
2
>>>
```